# How can I indent an example environment?

Tags: indentation

I am making some presentation material using beamer.

Because I am not used to using Latex, and this is the first time to use beamer, I am very not good at grammar of Latex and beamer. :(

Please let me know how to indent an example environment.

My code of one slide is like the following:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=0, t]{Inventory Control}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The \blue{Open-loop} minimization of the cost is to select all orders $u_0, \cdots, u_{N-1}$ at once at time $0$.
    \\[1.5em]
    \item The \blue{Closed-loop} minimization of the cost is to postpone placing the order $u_k$ until the last possible moment (time $k$) when the current stock $x_k$ will be know.
    \\[1.5em]
    \item[] Mathematically, in closed-loop inventory optimization, we want to find a sequence of functions $\mu_k, k=0, \cdots, k=N-1$, mapping stock $x_k$ into order $u_k$ so as to minimize the expected cost, where
    $$\mu_k(x_k) = \text{amount that should be ordered at time } k \text{ if the stock is } x_k.$$
    \\[0.5em]
    \item The \blue{Policy} (or \blue{control law})
    $$\pi=\left\{\mu_0, \mu_1, \cdots, \mu_{N-1}\right\}$$

    \begin{example}
        For each $\pi$, the corresponding cost for a fixed initial stock $x_0$ is
        $$J_{\pi}(x_0)=E\left\{R(x_N)+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(r(x_k)+c\mu_k(x_k)\right)\right\}$$
    \end{example}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The result of the above code is like the following:
[image: 111]

However, I want to make like the following, please help me.
[image: 112]

Comment: I guess it's caused by too low shrink factor. Please try your example with `shrink = 25`, for instance. Is it then what you need?

Comment: I hope the example to be like the below. How can I adapted shrink in the environment?? I tried \begin[shrink=25]{example} ~ but not worked.

Comment: I meant the `shrink` option of the frame

Comment: but if you need only to center example environment and have it narrower then the whole `\textwidth`, you can try to wrap it in `minipage` of a desired width and then in `center` environment. Thus  something like`\begin{center} \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth} \begin{example}...  \end{example} \end{minipage} \end{center}`

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Wow wow wow wow!!! You are very AWESOME! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `example` block in a `minipage` of width `\linewidth` - the line width within a list (like `itemize`), it'll stay put:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=0, t]{Inventory Control}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item The \textcolor{blue}{Open-loop} minimization of the cost is to 
      select all orders $u_0, \cdots, u_{N-1}$ at once at time~$0$.

    \item The \textcolor{blue}{Closed-loop} minimization of the cost is to 
      postpone placing the order~$u_k$ until the last possible moment 
      (time~$k$) when the current stock~$x_k$ will be know.

      Mathematically, in closed-loop inventory optimization, we want to 
      find a sequence of functions $\mu_k, k = 0, \cdots, k = N - 1$, 
      mapping stock~$x_k$ into order~$u_k$ so as to minimize the expected 
      cost, where

      \[
        \mu_k(x_k) = \text{amount that should be ordered at time } k 
          \text{ if the stock is } x_k.
      \]

    \item The \textcolor{blue}{Policy} (or \textcolor{blue}{control law})
      \[
        \pi = \bigl\{ \mu_0, \mu_1, \cdots, \mu_{N-1} \bigr\}
      \]

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{example}
      For each~$\pi$, the corresponding cost for a fixed initial stock~$x_0$ is
      \[
        J_{\pi}(x_0) = E \left\{ R(x_N) + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
          \bigl( r(x_k) + c\mu_k(x_k) \bigr) \right\}
      \]
    \end{example}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code as well as use `\[`...`\]` for display math rather than `$$`...`$$`. See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: May I ask you one more? Is there any way to change word Example to other word? For example, Result.

Comment: @Danny_Kim: To your preamble add either (1) `\theoremstyle{example} \newtheorem{result}[theorem]{\translate{Result}}` and use `\begin{result}`...`\end{result}` or (2) `\usepackage{etoolbox} \patchcmd{\example}{Example}{Result}{}{}` and keep using `\begin{example}`...`\end{example}`. Option (1) is preferred for it provides a syntax that matches the output and is more flexible.